# facebook open graph story displaying in activity log but not in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created facebook open graph story and get JavaScript code.When i use this JavaScript code the story display in my activity log but not display in my time line.Right now the story is not approved by facebook.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.1#explicitsharing
hope it helps you.